# All links contained in the page removed http or https in Laravel website

Tags: laravel, http, https, protocols, prefix

Below is the file of `/routes/web.php` and declared 3 routes as following: [web.php code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQpyk.png)

1. xx.com/contact
2. xx.com/ooo/contact
3. xx.com/vendor/contact

The problem is in the route `xx.com/contact` and `xx.com/ooo/contact` all links contained in the page are without protocol (http or https), please find the screenshot below.
[output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oe8V0.png)

with prefix `/ooo/` (`xx.com/ooo/contact`) also the same are without protocol.
[output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GuIpP.png)

However in the prefix `/vendor/` (`xx.com/vendor/contact`) all page links are with protocol (http or https), please find the screenshot below.
[output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRzg4.png)

Please help what is the solution to stop removing the protocol, as I want the whole site links contained in the page with the protocol (http or https).

Thank you!

---------ADD ON------

For the layout blade I had removed everything (js and css) just wrote http and https for testing as [code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysgX9.png)

`xx.com/testing` output is removed http: and https: [output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ysJp.png)

`xx.com/ooo/testing` output is removed http: and https: [output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4udqE.png)

However, with the prefix `/vendor/` (`xx.com/vendor/testing`) is working fine, it is with protocol (http or https) [output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYRWY.png)

Please HELP...

Comment: in the `.env` file set `ASSET_URL=https://your.app.url #for production` 
 and in blade `<link href="{{ asset( '' file ") }}"`

Comment: Are those 3 route use the same layout blade file? Can you post the contents of your layout blade file?

Comment: Hi, yes 3 route are using same layout blade. Please find the ADD ON information in the question.